# Fixed search button top bar

Tags: css, facebook, search

I'm trying to make a fixed top bar with a search button, facebook login, etc...
The bar is fine, the problem is, the search button is moving along the page when it changes the resolution, I want it fixed like the facebook login bar, so it doesn't matter if you change the resolution, all the buttons have to move with the topbar, what do I have to do?
Thanks.

```
.fixbar {
width: 100%;
position: fixed;
left: 0px;
top: 0px;
height: 30px;
background-image: url(../img/fixbar.png);
background-repeat: repeat-x;
z-index: 1;
bottom: 0px;
}


#search {
position: fixed;
left: 396px;
top: 0px;
width: 100%;
height: 22px;
z-index: 2;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set position:fixed .fixbar class and then u need to set position:absolute to the #search id.

**CSS**

```
.fixbar {
    width: 100%;
    height:30px;
    position: fixed;
    left: 0px;
    top: 0px;
    right:0 height: 30px;
    background: red;
    z-index: 1;
}
#search {
    position: absolute;
    right:20px;
    top: 0px;
    width: 30px;
    height: 22px;
    z-index: 2;
    background:blue;

}
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="fixbar">
    <div id="search"></div>
</div>
```

*output in here*

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/tutspack/Nargu/)

Comment: yes but that way the search button moves as the page changes the resolution, I wanted it fixed in a position no matter the resolution is

Comment: Search id within a parent element called .fixbar class.So if are changing resolution #search bar going together with parent element.This is the way we are doing it normaly

Answer (score 0):

Sorry I do not understood your question.
Let's play with a live example and i'll try to unsderstand and maybe can help you.
Have a look at: http://jsfiddle.net/xdEUN/

```
<div class="wrapper">
<div class="fixbar">
<input type="search" id="search" />
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: I want a bar just like the facebook one, with home button, search and whatever.